# Packaging a Perl application

Tags: perl, packaging, dancer

I need to package a [Perl Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) application for installation using RPM. Pretty much all of the Perl module/distribution tools deal with installing files into Perl specific locations, such as /usr/lib/perl. I need to be able to create an installation in a self contained location, such as /opt/foo.

I know about [App::Build](http://search.cpan.org/~mbarbon/App-Build-0.73/), which looks like it might be useful, and provides facilities missing from Module::Build. I expect there might be a [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org/) plugin to do this sort of thing but I've been unable to locate one.

What tools would you suggest using for building, testing and packaging a Perl 'application'?

The layout of the application would follow normal Dancer style, with /public, /views, /lib, etc

Comment: I'd suggest using the tools provided by the distro you are building the RPM for. Debian has a packaging kit for Perl modules (to make debs with), I'd assume that RPM based distros would have something similar.

Comment: Yes, rpmbuild will doubtless be tasked with actually putting the RPM together, but I'm more looking for Perl tooling for managing dependencies, testing, resource files and that sort of thing. Module::Build/Dist::Zilla do great jobs for this, but are targeted at modules/distributions, not so great for 'applications'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken in saying that Module::Build is missing the functionality to install additional (non-lib) directories. See the [Cookbook](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCookbook#Adding_new_elements_to_the_install_process).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps at all. It describes what we do at work:

http://www.slideshare.net/p3castro/packaging-perl

Caveat: we use a common Perl install across all applications.